# Storing Reference Files that Are Not a Part of the Program

Tags: github

I am working on a [Firefox extension](https://github.com/msaroff/bbCodeWebEx/issues) it is a context menu for automating bbCode, HTML, MarkDown, etc.

It is functional now, but I have a file which is the size of the rest of the code combined, an Excel spreadsheet. (Yes, I know, lame)

I use it as a database for organizing the menu IDs, arguments, internationalization, etc.

It's useful, for me at least, and I want to make it available, but it is not properly a part of the application, it should be a part of the background documentation.

Is there a way in Github/Git to separate documentary files from those that a part of execution of the code?

I've looked through Github, and I haven't found a spot (with revision control) to put this.

Comment: Github is not used to store programs. It's used to store whatever sources you need to create, build, document, demo etc. your program. Most github repos have a README file. This file isn't part of any program. Why do you think you can't store such a file in the git repo?

Comment: It isn't exactly documentation, it's a central of context menu settings and i19n stuff that is converter to JSON for the program.  So, I want it stored, and revision controlled, but not to be in the XPI when released.  I guess I will just delete manually when making the XPI file,

Comment: So what. if it's needed, for whatever reason, for your program, then store it in your gi repo. There's nothing wrong with that. that's the reason git repos exist.